# CCAI send message api not working giving error invalid message format

Tags: dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx, contact-center

I'm working on a project where I need to use the send message api of ccai
https://externals.ujet.co/apidocs/apps/publication.html#jump-Chats-Sendamessageinachat

I'm getting `invalid message format` error. I followed the same body format that is given in the api documentation

```
{
    "from_user_id": 2,
    "message": {
        "message": {
            "type": "text",
            "content": {
                "text": "hai welcome"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me find out what is wrong in this.

Comment: Hi @Sariga, Could you provide the documentation that you followed ?

Comment: @DhirajSingh https://externals.ujet.co/apidocs/apps/publication.html#jump-Chats-Sendamessageinachat this one